# Permute Array Such That All Neighbors Are Altered

Tags: arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

I have this circular array, and I need to permute it somehow such that every element has both its neighbors altered.

Example:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

becomes

```
3 1 4 2 5
```

The restriction is that the array needs to be at least 5 elements otherwise it's impossible.

Been trying to solve it for a long time, I'm sure it has a name but I had no luck finding the answer online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very easy to solve, you just need to find some strategy that works for odd and even number of elements in the array:

*First choose all numbers at even positions, then the first number at an odd position, followed by the last number at an odd position and finally the rest of the numbers at odd positions.*

12345 becomes 13524, so it works for an odd amount of elements.

123456 becomes 135264, so it works for an even amount of elements.

0123456789 becomes 0246819357, another example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are aware of choose-permute-unchoose paradigm to solve such problems. Having said that, during choose what you need to do is when you are choosing make sure that you are not choosing a neighbor so for example your current permutation is 1 2 3 4 5 i.e. your current string is 1, rest is 2 3 4 5. Now you have to choose from 2 3 4 5, but your current string has 1, so you shouldn't choose 2. you should choose 3 instead. and so on.